# Javascript color code variables inside the css file (React JS)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have the list of color codes in the JS file.

JavaScript:

```
export var ColorCodes = { 
    first:'#D09FD2',  
    second:'#A72500',  
    third:'#F67GHI',   
    fourth:'#8FERDD',  
}
```

I tried to use the js variables inside the CSS file like below.

it throws errors.

CSS:

```
import 'my.js'

.firstColor{

    font-size:15px;
    color:ColorCodes.first;
    }

.secColor{

    font-size:12px;
    color:ColorCodes.second;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="firstColor">aaa</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

you cannot use js inside css, instead you should abstract your color codes inside your css and then use dynamic classes via javascript

Answer (score 2):

There is a thing you can try, according with w3 it works, check it [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/) .

```
:root {
  --first-color: #D09FD2;
  --second-color: #A72500;
  --third-color: #F67GHI;
  --fourth-color: #8FERDD;
}

.firstColor{

    font-size:15px;
    color:var(--first-color);
    }

.secColor{

    font-size:12px;
    color:var(--second-color);
    }
```

Comment: I didn't know CSS supported this. Thanks